# Regex - non capturing group is not working

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings, an example is:

`s = 'Albany To Westgate Via Riverhead'`

All the strings are of the form 'X To Y Via Z', or 'X To Y'.

I want to extract Y, in the example, "Westgate" from the strings.

I cannot simply do

`re.match('\w+ To (w*) Via w*',s).group(1)`
because the "Via" may or may not exist...

For the example, I wrote:

`re.match('\w+ To (.+(?=\sVia .*$)?)',s).group(1)`
but this returns 'Westgate Riverhead' and I don't understand why ~ anything after via should be captured in group 2 and should not show up.

Also, 
`re.match('\w+ To (.+(?=\sVia .*$)?)',s).group(2)` returns none - which means for some reason group 2 is not matching anything?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `re.match('\w+ To (.+(?=\sVia .*$)?)',s).group(1)` returns `'Westgate Via Riverhead'`

Comment: If you put your existing regex of `\w+ To (.+(?=\sVia .*$)?)` into regex101 or similar you'll see that you only have one capturing group.  Example: https://regex101.com/r/mmGMqJ/1.  Following that link hover the cursor over the green text highlighted and it's both group one and there is no group two.  You may think you have two groups being captured but nope - only one. 
 In that link I've put another pattern you can copy and paste into the regex box. For one thing you have `$` in the optional part but you will have an end with or without `Via` right? so it has to be after this for one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more generic regex that allows for the destinations to have more than one word and potentially punctuation as well:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'.*?\s+to\s+(.+?)(?:\s+via\b.+)?$', re.I)

print(regex.match('Albany To Westgate Via Riverhead').group(1))
print(regex.match('New York to London').group(1))
print(regex.match('Barcelona to San Jose').group(1))
print(regex.match('New York to Los Angeles via St. Louis').group(1))
```

Output:

```
Westgate
London
San Jose
Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-capturing groups do work, if you use them correctly. In this case:

```
s = 'Albany To Westgate Via Riverhead'
r = re.match(r'(\w+) To (\w+)(?:\sVia (\w+)$)?',s)
# r.group(1) == 'Albany', r.group(2) == 'Westgate', r.group(3) == 'Riverhead'
```